# How to invoke PartialViewResult in chain using AJAX in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, partial

Let's say we've got list of 200 objects to process. Processing one of these objects takes some time, approx. 5 seconds. What I do now is processing them all in one loop in a single PartialViewResult:

```
    public PartialViewResult Sync()
    {
        var items = Reps.Apt.GetAllUnique();
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            Process(item);
        }
        return PartialView();
    }
```

And it takes several minutes until the result page appears.

Basicly, what I want to achieve is: call Process method on the first object, update PartialView with information, like: Element #1 done..., call Process method on the 2nd object, update view and so on until end of the list. So the user will know the progress of whole processing.

Is it possible?

Comment: I'm afraid you take the wrong approach. You should either poll the progress - and doing the processing on a different -background - thread, or drive the processing from javascript - bad idea(tm).

Answer (score 1):

There is an article in MSDN magazine that addresses the exact issue you are discussing:

[A Context-Sensitive Progress Bar for ASP.NET MVC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh580729.aspx)